# Solar high voltage regulator & power logger circuit - design review

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, mosfet-driver, stm8

I was wondering whether someone could give me some feedback on a circuit I have been throwing together. The circuit is supposed to act as an voltage regulator and power logger for my high voltage solar array (400 V max). Since the desired output voltage is never supposed to be higher than the array voltage, I chose a buck converter topology. Up until this point, I have not built such high voltage circuits and I'm therefore not that confident in my design.

My major concerns are:

- Are the isolation distances big enough?
- Do I need to add additional protection to the buck converter (e.g. Zener diodes on GS)? (answered)
- Is it OK to have the ground planes "split" like that or should they be connected?
- Do I need complete isolation of HV/LV?
- Are the bootstrap caps big enough?

PS: Please excuse my English, I'm not a native speaker.

Note: fixed freewheel diodes (replaced by low side mosfet), half-bridge, added gate zeners, increased resistor count im voltage divider

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Arent D6/D7 backwards? Your inductor is labeled 470uF. Not sure if a 400V buck converter is a nice DIY side project. Pretty dangerous.

Comment: why are D6 n D7 reverse?!! If this is a mistake and u would want to correct, then how would the IR21xx be going to work?? its bootstrap won't work this way cuz there's no low-side Mosfet to charge the capacitor!!!

Comment: Uhh, yeah diodes were backwards. Regarding the bootstrap cap charging: How can i fix that? Do I need to add a low side mosfet and half bridge driver? Does that mess with the buck converter?

Comment: Ok, changed the buck converter to half bridge without diode in the schematic.

Comment: Zeners on FETS gs close to FETS slightly above Vdrive max keeps Vgate < Vgsmax when Murphy decies to use Millar capacitance to couple in Vd HV spikes to gate. || One more resistor in the HV divider change may stave off  a bad day (any one R fail short ...) . | R15, R16 1 Watt | | 10V on gate should be fine. More OK as Vgsmax is 30V but the more headroom the safer [Datasheet](http://www.meipusen.com/uploadfile/2019/0121/20190121091536770.pdf)  - That said 15V - Vdiode drop etc gives you SLIGHTLY better Rdson.

Comment: Do Ch1DRV CH2DRV floar briefly at startup prior to STM8 asserting control? . (Maybe SLM2103 has pulldown). Can be fun to have a blip of HV unexpectedly at startuo.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of that. Forgot that pulldown when going from high side switch to full bridge driver.